# How did the Tal Shiar rebuild but the Obsidian Order couldn't?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, romulan

In the two-part DS9 episodes *Improbable Cause* and *The Die Is Cast*, the Romulan secret police (Tal Shiar) worked with the Cardassian Obsidian Order to create a joint fleet intended to eradicate the rulers of the Dominion -- only for both organizations to be led into a trap and be exterminated.

However, while the Obsidian Order was considered to be extinct for good, the Tal Shair was somehow reformed in later seasons -- so why couldn't the Obsidian Order be rebuilt as well?

Comment: seems like the Obsidian Order committed all their resources and personel and the Tal Shiar didn't. Clever Romulans. Similar to the story of the chicken and the pig. The Obsidian Order was committed, the Tal Shiar was only involved. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicken_and_the_Pig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Tal Shiar had more support from the government.** It was customary for the head of the Tal Shiar to sit on the [Continuing Committee](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan_Continuing_Committee), the highest advisors to the Praetor, and some high-ranking Tal Shiar leaders (such as vice chairman Vreenak) were also Senators. The Tal Shiar were also responsible for high-profile duties for the government such as security for diplomatic conferences. In general the Tal Shiar seems to enjoy a good deal of support from the Romulan Senate.

The Obsidian Order, in contrast, was the victim of a regime change on Cardassia. When Central Command was overthrown in favor of the [Detapa Council](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Detapa_Council), the Order was a symbol of the old regime's repression. Then the Dominion took control of Cardassian affairs, with even more reason to distrust the Order. Accordingly, **the Order was replaced** by the [Cardassian Intelligence Bureau](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cardassian_Intelligence_Bureau), which had a similar role and duties but presumably had been purged of elements that would be a threat to the Council and the Dominion.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the Obsidian Order was explicitly supposed to not have any ships. But the event of [the DS9 episode Defiant](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/455.htm) expose a major rift between the Obsidian Order and the Cardassian Military

> DUKAT: But there's nothing of any value in that sector.
> SISKO: There must be something. Are there any Class-M planets there?
> DUKAT: There's one. Orias Three. But it's uninhabited, it's desolate.
> SISKO: But everything seems to point to the Orias System. It might be worth your sending one of your warships there just in case the Defiant does show up.
> DUKAT: All right. Contact Gul Ranor. Tell him to dispatch one warship
> KORINAS: No. You'll send no ships to the Orias system.
> DUKAT: You're here as an observer. You have no authority
> KORINAS: That sector is under direct control of the Obsidian Order and you will not enter it.
> DUKAT: Why?
> KORINAS: That matter's classified.
> DUKAT: Well you can file a complaint with the Central Command later. Open a channel to Gul Ranor now.
> KORINAS: Any warship sent into the Orias system will be destroyed.
> DUKAT: Are you saying that you will fire on another Cardassian ship?
> KORINAS: What I am saying is that the Obsidian Order will take whatever steps are necessary to protect the Orias system. And so will I.

Later

> DUKAT: When you make out your report for the Obsidian Order be sure to mention the fact that I could have prevented the Defiant from reaching Orias if you hadn't interfered.
> KORINAS: They will never reach Orias. You can count on that.
> SOLDIER: Three more ships have just appeared in the Orias system.
> DUKAT: What kind of ships?
> SOLDIER: Cardassian warships. Keldon Class.
> DUKAT: Whose ships are those, Korinas?
> KORINAS: Why are you asking me?
> DUKAT: Because if they were military ships, I would know about them. So that leaves the Obsidian Order.
> SISKO: I thought the Obsidian Order didn't have any ships.
> DUKAT: They're not supposed to. In fact, they are explicitly forbidden from having military equipment of any kind.
> (Korinas smiles and walks out.)

The ships here were the ones that would attempt to destroy the Founders and be wiped out by the Dominion. It would make sense that the Cardassians would not want to rebuild an organization that had openly defied the previous government.

By contrast, the Romulans are a nearly-paranoid culture. Part of that is partially due to the [Zhat Vash](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zhat_Vash), a near-religious cult within the Tal Shiar dedicated to

> ensuring that artificial life never rises to threaten organic life

That zeal, combined with the natural paranoia of the Romulans, likely played an enormous role in ensuring they continued on.

Comment: This would be the Zhat Vash that quite happily ignored Data for decades as well as the Romulan's own Institute of Robotics....